# Python List Assignment Not Having Any Effect

Tags: python, arrays

I'm relatively new to Python.

I'm trying to implement merge sort in python. However, a test case like [1, 2, 6, 4, 5]   came out to be [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] when "sorted." After a long time, I found the cause to be in the merge algorithm. The actual algorithm looked fine, except I don't know why a certain part isn't working.

```
def merge(arr, left, right, start_pos):
   i = 0
   j = 0
   k = start_pos

   while i < len(left) or j < len(right):
       if i >= len(left):
           arr[k] = right[j] # This assignment has no effect
           j += 1
           k += 1
       elif j >= len(right):
           arr[k] = left[i] # Same here
           i += 1
           k += 1
       else:
           if arr[i] < arr[j]:
               arr[k] = arr[i] # Here
               i += 1
               k += 1
           else:
               arr[k] = arr[j] # And here
               j += 1
               k += 1
```

First of all, the goal was to be given an array called `arr`, and array called `left`, an array called `right`, and an int called `start_pos`, the merge algorithm replaces the values in `arr` starting at `start_pos` with `left` and `right` merged. However, as you can see in the comments, for some reason the assigment isn't working. I couldn't seem to figure out why. It probably won't be that much help, but just in case here is the whole code:

```
def merge_sort(arr):
    merge_sort_helper(arr, 0, len(arr))

def merge_sort_helper(arr, left, right):
    if left >= right - 1:
        return

    mid = int((left + right) / 2)
    merge_sort_helper(arr, left, mid)
    merge_sort_helper(arr, mid, right)
    merge(arr, arr[left : mid], arr[mid : right], left)


def merge(arr, left, right, start_pos):
   i = 0
   j = 0
   k = start_pos

   while i < len(left) or j < len(right):
       if i >= len(left):
           arr[k] = right[j]
           j += 1
           k += 1
       elif j >= len(right):
           arr[k] = left[i]
           i += 1
           k += 1
       else:
           if arr[i] < arr[j]:
               arr[k] = arr[i]
               i += 1
               k += 1
           else:
               arr[k] = arr[j]
               j += 1
               k += 1
```

Comment: The list assignment statement is working as expected. The problem is with the value that you are assigning to that list.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  In particular, put in some strategic `print` commands to show what is actually happening as you work through the sort.  I *can't* see that the assignment isn't working, because you neglected to show us.

Comment: Most of all, what confuses my is how you expect the values you assign to a temporary, local variable to be transferred accurately back to the main list.  I don't think you quite understand which parameters are transient, and which map to variables in the main program (which you neglected to provide or trace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merge function intent to genrate new sorted list by left sorted list and right sorted list.
The error occur on `if arr[i] < arr[j]:`.
you don't want compare arr[i] and arr[j], the compared value should be left[i] and right[j], select the smaller one fill to arr.

Here is the modified code

```
def merge_sort(arr):
    merge_sort_helper(arr, 0, len(arr))

def merge_sort_helper(arr, left, right):
    if left >= right - 1:
        return

    mid = int((left + right) / 2)
    merge_sort_helper(arr, left, mid)
    merge_sort_helper(arr, mid, right)
    merge(arr, arr[left : mid], arr[mid : right], left)


def merge(arr, left, right, start_pos):
   i = 0
   j = 0
   k = start_pos

   while i < len(left) or j < len(right):
       if i >= len(left):
           arr[k] = right[j]
           j += 1
           k += 1
       elif j >= len(right):
           arr[k] = left[i]
           i += 1
           k += 1
       else:
           if left[i] < right[j]:
               arr[k] = left[i]
               i += 1
               k += 1
           else:
               arr[k] = right[j]
               j += 1
               k += 1

l = [8,1,3,5,7,6,4,2,9]
merge_sort(l)
print(l)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that typo.

Answer (score 1):

Your calling of `merge` function seems to be culprit, where you're passing in the same list `arr` 3 times.

You would want the `merge` function to return a new list that is the merged output of `left` and `right`. This would also help you see the recursion in `merge_helper` more clearly